# Write a Splitted PDF Back to HDFS using Python Insecure Client

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf, data-preprocessing

I have used the PdfFileReader to read the file from the Data Lake and my requirement is to split the read PDF into individual pages and write back individual files back to a different folder in HDFS.

For reading files i have used below code and is working.

```
        from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
        from io import BytesIO
        from hdfs import InsecureClient
        client = InsecureClient('http://datalake:50070')
        import requests
        from json import dumps
        
        client.status("/")
        fnames=client.list('/shared/Team5162')
        with client.read('/shared/Team5162/DemoCompany/Green Energy Limited.pdf') as reader:
                input_pdf = PdfFileReader(BytesIO(reader.read()))
        print(input_pdf.getNumPages())
```

I will get the number of pages.
[enter image description here][1]

Now i want to split the read PDF and write back.

```
        for i in range(input_pdf.getNumPages()):
            out_pdf  = PdfFileWriter()
            output   = out_pdf.appendPagesFromReader(input_pdf)
            filename = "/shared/Team5162/demopdf/"+"document-page%s.pdf" % i
            with client.write(filename) as writeStream:
                    writeStream.write(output)
```

Using this code am able to create 136 individual pages.However it has no content embedded and i gets no error as well.

Could you please comment.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfLzA.png

Comment: `appendPagesFromReader` is going to append ALL the pages, isn't it?

Comment: As per the doc it should Copy pages from reader to writer https://www.kite.com/python/docs/PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter.appendPagesFromReader

Comment: Yes, but you're calling it 136 times.  Won't the first call copy all of the pages at once?

Comment: I replaced the method with addPage as my requirement is to split the PDF into individual pages and write each splitted pdf into data lake.                                         
                                                                                                                                        for i in range(input_pdf.getNumPages()):
    out_pdf  = PdfFileWriter()
    output   = out_pdf.addPage(input_pdf.getPage(i))
    filename = "/shared/Team5162/demopdf/"+"document-page%s.pdf" % i
    with client.write(filename) as writeStream:
           writeStream.write(output)

Comment: Experts Kindly me know.

Comment: There is a command line tool called `pdfseparate` that can do this job.